# After listing the uploaded files in the view how to view the listed files in browser codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, download

> My Controller

```
    /*Task Attachment List*/
public function get_task_attachments()
{
    $task_id = $this->input->post('id',true);
    $attachment =  $this->technical_user_model->get_task_attachments($task_id);
  // echo json_encode($attachment);
   $output = null;

    foreach ( $attachment as $row)
   {
       //   here we build a dropdown item line for each
       // query result
      $path = $row['Attachment_Path'];
      $folder=$row['Project_Name'];
      $output .= "<li class='list-group-item'> <a target='_blank' href='download/$folder/$path' >".$row['Attachment_Path']."</a></li>";
   }
   echo $output;

}
/*Task Attachment List*/
```

> I have listed the uploaded files. How to view it in the browser instead of downloading it.

Comment: Which type of files do you have pdf, image or something else ?

Comment: I'm Uploading all kind of files like .zip,doc,pdf,img,txt,ppt

Comment: doc pdf ppt & image  will only displays in browsers

Comment: ok..how to view it??

Comment: @Vignesh Thangavel check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only limited files can be viewed in browser like

`.png, .pdf, .txt, .ppt, .doc` etc.

And some files cannot be viewed in browser but they will download like,

`.zip, .rar, .exe` etc.

So to view file in browser, you can use something like

`<a href="file_path" target="_blank">Click to view</a>`

Comment: only image are opening. other files getting downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should return this http header:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

For viewing in browser it should also return:

```
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="myfile.pdf"
```